# How can I tell whether a waveguide supports hybrid modes or not?

Tags: electromagnetism, microwave, optical-fibre, waveguide

When studying metallic waveguides, it was taken for granted that the TE and TM (and potentially TEM) formed a complete set, that is, any electromagnetic field in the waveguide could be written as a linear combination of such modes.
When we moved on to optical waveguides, such as fibers, we were told that TE and TM modes were no longer sufficient and hybrid modes had to be included to make a complete set.
My question is this: how do I understand whether a waveguide necessitates hybrid modes to form a complete set or not? Is there any mathematical proof that in metallic waveguides TE and TM modes form a complete set but in fibers they do not?

Comment: Most fibers (so called single mode fibers) only support a hybrid mode.  The reason for this is the boundary conditions imposed by the dielectric waveguide, which are different than a metallic waveguide.  Most EM or photonics texts will include a complete derivation for both boundary conditions.

Comment: @user1850479 most texts include the derivation of the modes, not the proof of their completeness.